# Cutting a live stream into separate mp4 files

Tags: c#, azure, video, ffmpeg, live-streaming

I am doing a research for cutting a live stream in piece and save it as mp4 files. I am using this source for the proof of concept:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-dotnet-creating-live-encoder-enabled-channel#download-sample

And this is the example code I use:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace AMSLiveTest
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string StreamingEndpointName = "streamingendpoint001";
        private const string ChannelName = "channel001";
        private const string AssetlName = "asset001";
        private const string ProgramlName = "program001";

        // Read values from the App.config file.
        private static readonly string _mediaServicesAccountName =
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MediaServicesAccountName"];
        private static readonly string _mediaServicesAccountKey =
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MediaServicesAccountKey"];

        // Field for service context.
        private static CloudMediaContext _context = null;
        private static MediaServicesCredentials _cachedCredentials = null;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create and cache the Media Services credentials in a static class variable.
            _cachedCredentials = new MediaServicesCredentials(
            _mediaServicesAccountName,
            _mediaServicesAccountKey);
            // Used the cached credentials to create CloudMediaContext.
            _context = new CloudMediaContext(_cachedCredentials);

            IChannel channel = CreateAndStartChannel();

            // Set the Live Encoder to point to the channel's input endpoint:
            string ingestUrl = channel.Input.Endpoints.FirstOrDefault().Url.ToString();

            // Use the previewEndpoint to preview and verify
            // that the input from the encoder is actually reaching the Channel.
            string previewEndpoint = channel.Preview.Endpoints.FirstOrDefault().Url.ToString();

            IProgram program = CreateAndStartProgram(channel);
            ILocator locator = CreateLocatorForAsset(program.Asset, program.ArchiveWindowLength);
            IStreamingEndpoint streamingEndpoint = CreateAndStartStreamingEndpoint();
            GetLocatorsInAllStreamingEndpoints(program.Asset);

            // Once you are done streaming, clean up your resources.
            Cleanup(streamingEndpoint, channel);
        }

        public static IChannel CreateAndStartChannel()
        {
            //If you want to change the Smooth fragments to HLS segment ratio, you would set the ChannelCreationOptions’s Output property.

            IChannel channel = _context.Channels.Create(
            new ChannelCreationOptions
            {
            Name = ChannelName,
            Input = CreateChannelInput(),
            Preview = CreateChannelPreview()
            });

            //Starting and stopping Channels can take some time to execute. To determine the state of operations after calling Start or Stop, query the IChannel.State .

            channel.Start();

            return channel;
        }

        private static ChannelInput CreateChannelInput()
        {
            return new ChannelInput
            {
                StreamingProtocol = StreamingProtocol.RTMP,
                AccessControl = new ChannelAccessControl
                {
                    IPAllowList = new List<IPRange>
                            {
                            new IPRange
                        {
                            Name = "TestChannelInput001",
                            // Setting 0.0.0.0 for Address and 0 for SubnetPrefixLength
                            // will allow access to IP addresses.
                            Address = IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0"),
                            SubnetPrefixLength = 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        private static ChannelPreview CreateChannelPreview()
        {
            return new ChannelPreview
            {
                AccessControl = new ChannelAccessControl
                {
                    IPAllowList = new List<IPRange>
                    {
                        new IPRange
                        {
                            Name = "TestChannelPreview001",
                            // Setting 0.0.0.0 for Address and 0 for SubnetPrefixLength
                            // will allow access to IP addresses.
                            Address = IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0"),
                            SubnetPrefixLength = 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        public static void UpdateCrossSiteAccessPoliciesForChannel(IChannel channel)
        {
            var clientPolicy =
                @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
            <access-policy>
                <cross-domain-access>
                    <policy>
                        <allow-from http-request-headers=""*"" http-methods=""*"">
                            <domain uri=""*""/>
                        </allow-from>
                        <grant-to>
                           <resource path=""/"" include-subpaths=""true""/>
                        </grant-to>
                    </policy>
                </cross-domain-access>
            </access-policy>";

            var xdomainPolicy =
                @"<?xml version=""1.0"" ?>
            <cross-domain-policy>
                <allow-access-from domain=""*"" />
            </cross-domain-policy>";

            channel.CrossSiteAccessPolicies.ClientAccessPolicy = clientPolicy;
            channel.CrossSiteAccessPolicies.CrossDomainPolicy = xdomainPolicy;

            channel.Update();
        }

        public static IProgram CreateAndStartProgram(IChannel channel)
        {
            IAsset asset = _context.Assets.Create(AssetlName, AssetCreationOptions.None);

            // Create a Program on the Channel. You can have multiple Programs that overlap or are sequential;
            // however each Program must have a unique name within your Media Services account.
            IProgram program = channel.Programs.Create(ProgramlName, TimeSpan.FromHours(3), asset.Id);
            program.Start();

            return program;
        }

        public static ILocator CreateLocatorForAsset(IAsset asset, TimeSpan ArchiveWindowLength)
        {
            // You cannot create a streaming locator using an AccessPolicy that includes write or delete permissions.            

            var locator = _context.Locators.CreateLocator
                (
                    LocatorType.OnDemandOrigin,
                    asset,
                    _context.AccessPolicies.Create
                    (
                        "Live Stream Policy",
                        ArchiveWindowLength,
                        AccessPermissions.Read
                    )
                );

            return locator;
        }

        public static IStreamingEndpoint CreateAndStartStreamingEndpoint()
        {
            var options = new StreamingEndpointCreationOptions
            {
                Name = StreamingEndpointName,
                ScaleUnits = 1,
                AccessControl = GetAccessControl(),
                CacheControl = GetCacheControl()
            };

            IStreamingEndpoint streamingEndpoint = _context.StreamingEndpoints.Create(options);
            streamingEndpoint.Start();

            return streamingEndpoint;
        }

        private static StreamingEndpointAccessControl GetAccessControl()
        {
            return new StreamingEndpointAccessControl
            {
                IPAllowList = new List<IPRange>
                {
                    new IPRange
                    {
                        Name = "Allow all",
                        Address = IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0"),
                        SubnetPrefixLength = 0
                    }
                },

                AkamaiSignatureHeaderAuthenticationKeyList = new List<AkamaiSignatureHeaderAuthenticationKey>
                {
                    new AkamaiSignatureHeaderAuthenticationKey
                    {
                        Identifier = "My key",
                        Expiration = DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromDays(365),
                        Base64Key = Convert.ToBase64String(GenerateRandomBytes(16))
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        private static byte[] GenerateRandomBytes(int length)
        {
            var bytes = new byte[length];
            using (var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                rng.GetBytes(bytes);
            }

            return bytes;
        }

        private static StreamingEndpointCacheControl GetCacheControl()
        {
            return new StreamingEndpointCacheControl
            {
                MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000)
            };
        }

        public static void UpdateCrossSiteAccessPoliciesForStreamingEndpoint(IStreamingEndpoint streamingEndpoint)
        {
            var clientPolicy =
                @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
            <access-policy>
                <cross-domain-access>
                    <policy>
                        <allow-from http-request-headers=""*"" http-methods=""*"">
                            <domain uri=""*""/>
                        </allow-from>
                        <grant-to>
                           <resource path=""/"" include-subpaths=""true""/>
                        </grant-to>
                    </policy>
                </cross-domain-access>
            </access-policy>";

            var xdomainPolicy =
                @"<?xml version=""1.0"" ?>
            <cross-domain-policy>
                <allow-access-from domain=""*"" />
            </cross-domain-policy>";

            streamingEndpoint.CrossSiteAccessPolicies.ClientAccessPolicy = clientPolicy;
            streamingEndpoint.CrossSiteAccessPolicies.CrossDomainPolicy = xdomainPolicy;

            streamingEndpoint.Update();
        }

        public static void GetLocatorsInAllStreamingEndpoints(IAsset asset)
        {
            var locators = asset.Locators.Where(l => l.Type == LocatorType.OnDemandOrigin);
            var ismFile = asset.AssetFiles.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.EndsWith(".ism"));
            var template = new UriTemplate("{contentAccessComponent}/{ismFileName}/manifest");
            var urls = locators.SelectMany(l =>
                        _context
                            .StreamingEndpoints
                            .AsEnumerable()
                            .Where(se => se.State == StreamingEndpointState.Running)
                            .Select(
                                se =>
                                    template.BindByPosition(new Uri("http://" + se.HostName),
                                    l.ContentAccessComponent,
                                        ismFile.Name)))
                        .ToArray();

        }

        public static void Cleanup(IStreamingEndpoint streamingEndpoint,
                                    IChannel channel)
        {
            if (streamingEndpoint != null)
            {
                streamingEndpoint.Stop();
                streamingEndpoint.Delete();
            }

            IAsset asset;
            if (channel != null)
            {

                foreach (var program in channel.Programs)
                {
                    asset = _context.Assets.Where(se => se.Id == program.AssetId)
                                            .FirstOrDefault();

                    program.Stop();
                    program.Delete();

                    if (asset != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var l in asset.Locators)
                            l.Delete();

                        asset.Delete();
                    }
                }

                channel.Stop();
                channel.Delete();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to make a method to cut a live stream for example every 15 minutes and save it as mp4 but don't know where to start.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Kind regards

UPDATE:

I want to save the mp4 files on my hard disk.

Comment: you want to save the live stream in your hard drive and keep it?

Comment: whats your live stream format?

Comment: Yes sir! I will add that in my question.

Comment: For the proof of concept I can use any live stream format. I can use youtube or the .manifest for azure like this: //amssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/91492735-c523-432b-ba01-faba6c2206a2/AzureMediaServicesPromo.ism/manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ffmpeg` to save the stream on your hard drive. Please see the code:

```
ffmpeg -i InputStreamURL -acodec aac -strict -2 -vcodec libx264 -hls_wrap 100 -f hls -hls_time 20 /var/www/html/ts/1.m3u8
```

The `-hls_time 20` use for the time of your saved data. In fact you use `ffmpeg` for a HLS stream but its doing the things you want. You could access the saved data on your Hard drive in `/var/www/html/ts/` (and you could change this as you want).

Or could use VLC :

```
cvlc -vvv rtp://@239.1.2.1:60001
--sout '#std{access=livehttp{seglen=5,delsegs=true,numsegs=5,
index=/path/to/stream.m3u8,
index-url=http://example.org/stream-########.ts},
mux=ts{use-key-frames},
dst=/path/to/stream-########.ts}'
```

In above command either you could change the duration of the saved data in hard drive. But I personally do not use VLC and prefer use `ffmpeg`

Finally you could call one of above command in your C# application and see the result. Good Luck.

Comment: Hello @combo_ci thanks for your time! When I replace the ***InputStreamURL*  with a youtube link I get this error:  `Invalid data found when processing input` and when I use the azure .manifest link I get this error: `No such file or directory`

Comment: why you use youtub or other source live ? i think its better to use your live streamer software..it do that ..you can set source of stream as you want

Comment: hi @combi_ci I just set up a stream with VLC when I change the stream url with my ip and port I get this error: `[http @ 0000000000f96f20] Stream ends prematurely at 0, should be 18446744073709551615 http://195.165.8.178:8080: I/O error`

Comment: @Fearhunter: i think we could not play youtub stream in vlc or other player...could you play that url in any player?

Comment: Yes I restart the stream and then I get this error: `[libx264 @ 0000000002b4bdc0] using SAR=196/201
[libx264 @ 0000000002b4bdc0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0000000002b4bdc0] profile High, level 1.2
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): No such file or directory
Error initializing output stream 0:0 --
[aac @ 0000000002b4c280] Qavg: 278.176
[aac @ 0000000002b4c280] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
Conversion failed!`

Comment: @Fearhunter: for last error it refer to the path that you want create files on hard disk...what's your path that you use in command?

Comment: Sorry my fault I made a syntax error your solution is working good! I wanna thank you for your time and have a nice day! `[flv @ 0000000000e630c0] New audio stream 0:459 at pos:900552 and DTS:732.28s
[flv @ 0000000000e630c0] New audio stream 0:460 at pos:901418 and DTS:732.333s
[flv @ 0000000000e630c0] New audio stream 0:461 at pos:903970 and DTS:732.385s
[flv @ 0000000000e630c0] New audio stream 0:462 at pos:904836 and DTS:732.437s
[flv @ 0000000000e630c0] New audio stream 0:463 at pos:907157 and DTS:732.489s`

Comment: Good Luck Fearhunter